# Angular 2 - Using RXJS Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following jsfiddle in Angular 1 which has two components, boxA, boxB that listens to a RXJS subject called msgSubject defined in msgService.

The mainCtrl broadcast a message through msgService broadcast function. If boxA and boxB are subscribed to the msgSubject (there is an option to unsubscribe) the updated message will show in each respective component view.

[Angular 1 Observable Js Fddile](https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/0maek0qr/)

My question is how do I replicate this in Angular 2? I've googled and most of the tutorials relate to HTTP and asynchronous search. I appreciate if someone can at least tell me the syntax to setup the subject, broadcast and subscribe. Any help I am so grateful for. Thanks in advance.

Angular 1 Code

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <style>

  .table-cell{
    border-right:1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/boxa">
  BoxA - Message Listener: </br>
  <strong>{{boxA.msg}}</strong></br>
  <button ng-click="boxA.unsubscribe()">Unsubscribe A</button>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/boxb">
    BoxB - Message Listener: </br>
  <strong>{{boxB.msg}}</strong></br>
  <button ng-click="boxB.unsubscribe()">Unsubscribe B</button>
 </script>

  <md-content class='md-padding'>
    <h3>
      {{name}}
    </h3>
    <label>Enter Text To Broadcast</label>
    <input ng-model='msg'/></br>
    <md-button class='md-primary' ng-click='broadcastFn()'>Broadcast</md-button></br>
    <h4>
    Components
    </h4>
    <box-a></box-a></br>
    <box-b></box-b>
  </md-content>





</div><!--end app-->
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,msgService) {

   $scope.name = "Observer App Example";
   $scope.msg = 'Message';
   $scope.broadcastFn = function(){
        msgService.broadcast($scope.msg);
   }


});

app.component("boxA",  {
      bindings: {},
      controller: function(msgService) {
        var boxA = this;
        boxA.msgService = msgService;

        boxA.msg = '';

        var boxASubscription = boxA.msgService.subscribe(function(obj) { 
            console.log('Listerner A');
          boxA.msg = obj;
                });

        boxA.unsubscribe = function(){
            console.log('Unsubscribe A');
            boxASubscription.dispose();
        };

      },
      controllerAs: 'boxA',
      templateUrl: "/boxa"
})
app.component("boxB",  {
      bindings: {},
      controller: function(msgService) {
        var boxB = this;
        boxB.msgService = msgService;

        boxB.msg = '';
        var boxBSubscription = boxB.msgService.subscribe(function(obj) { 
            console.log('Listerner B');
          boxB.msg = obj;
                });

        boxB.unsubscribe=function(){
            console.log('Unsubscribe B');
          boxBSubscription.dispose();
        };
      },
      controllerAs: 'boxB',
      templateUrl: "/boxb"
})

app.factory('msgService', ['$http', function($http){
    var msgSubject = new Rx.Subject();
    return{
        subscribe:function(subscription){
            return msgSubject.subscribe(subscription);
        },
        broadcast:function(msg){
        console.log('success');
            msgSubject.onNext(msg);
        }
    }   
}])
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a service to communicate between the two components:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class BroadcastService {

  private broadcastSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string streams
  // Return as observale to encapsulate the subject
  broadcastAnnounce$ = this.broadcastSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  announceBoradcast(message: string) {
    this.broadcastSource.next(message);
  }
}
```

Then in one components send a broadcast message:

```
BroadcastService.announceBoradcast("Hello World");
```

Then other component can subscribe to the broadcast:

```
BroadcastService.broadcastAnnounce$.subscribe((message) => {
    console.log(message);
})
```

Here is some more information on communication between components in Angular2:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thanks this looks exactly like what i want, will try it out and get back. Also.noob question what does the $  and <string>  mean?

Comment: It does nothing other than indicating it's an observable stream :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: @DNRN why not just use broadcastSource.subscribe() without creating at all broadcastAnnounce$