# angular 2 access tags outside router-outer (components)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my angular 2 project, when the app is loaded and first component is shown, I can click the fixed button in order to show the menu. But if I go to another route and try to click the button, nothing happens. The thing is, the button click events are described in jquery file which I load after component init like this - $.getScript('assets/js/app.js', function(){}); because I'm porting over the jquery website to angular.
My navbar tag is placed above the router-outer, above the view. Could that be the reason? I got a feeling parent DOM is not visible after view page is changed.

Structure of app:

```
<navbar></navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<pageFooter></pageFooter>
```

home component:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
...
      $.getScript('assets/js/app.js', function(){});
}
```

I've also tried to directly manipulate and navbar from child, using a jQuery to simply add the class, but it doesn't happen.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The parent DOM is not visible for the child

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "service" to communicate between the child and parent component.

I have responded to a similar question here:
[Angular 2 - Using RXJS Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762175/angular-2-using-rxjs-observables/39763021#39763021)

If you need any help, just ask in the comments :)

Comment: but then the questions is , how to service will change the DOM outside the view ? or how the service can call toggleMenu function in navbar component ?

Comment: You'll have some sort of event going on in your of your "routeroutlet" components, which needs to be propagated to the parent component, where navbar is part of. For this you use the service. Call the BroadcastService's announceBoradcast(), and subscribe to broadcastAnnounce$ in parent.

Comment: You can extend this fairly easy to use objects, or what you need to inform the parent component about.

Comment: You just subscribe to the services broadcastAnnounce$, and every subscriber will get the event, when you call announceBoradcast("Hello world")..

Comment: You might read up a bit on how to use rxjs. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmEvKLYF0os

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for now, I solved it by putting navbar tag inside a component view. I know its not a best solution and need to put navbar tag in every component but it works. But hopefully there is a better way. I dont know how to use a service in order to make my navbar component manipulate a DOM.

Comment: It's not the service which manipulates the DOM it's the parent component. But you need a service to communicate the event from a child to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of the component (tag) at compile time, you can just inject it:

```
constructor(private navBar:NavBarComponent) {}
```

This injects the closest ancestor component of that type.